# Linux Stripes on Screen

Tags: linux, debian, gpu, linux-mint, amd-gpu

I was building an Android application with using Android Studio Giraffe. Suddenly I saw some colorful squares and screen was frozen. I restarted it and it give me `kfd kfd amdgpu oland not supported in kfd` error. I tried to open compatibility mode and fix with installing amdgpu drivers but didn't work. I couldn't fresh Linux Mint install because I couldn't see installation screen. So I decided to install Debian 12. Everything went good until end of install. When I open my computer I saw screens below. First one is login screen second one is desktop screen. I think my GPU was broken but I would like to hear from you who know or see something like that.
GPU: AMD R7 250
OS: Linux Mint and Debian 12
[image: login screen]
[image: desktop]

---

**Update:**
It's moved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749362/linux-stripes-on-screen)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for idea. I asked my question on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing Windows first to determine if your GPU is functioning correctly. Furthermore, installing Windows can also help you ascertain if the issue is related to any hardware components.

Comment: It's a good idea. First I will try to boot with Windows and copy my files. Afterwards I will do fresh Linux install.

Comment: That certainly makes sense.